# How to access LAMP server via internet connection?

Tags: lamp

I have a headless lamp server running Arch-arm Linux server passing through a netgear wnr1000v3-genie router then to a modem and then to the world which I access via ssh and panic's transmit from a 10.9.5 Hackintosh.

I can access it via wifi from home but I'd like to access it via the internet.

The router goes to 10.0.0.1 for whatever reason. The server has a static ip assigned by the router as 10.0.0.3. The router also has a static internal address.

I have the following ports forwarded by the router out to 10.0.0.3: 21, 22, 80; 443.

EDIT: I have been assured by my ISP that no ports are being blocked.  However, when I try the good old 8080->80 trick I still am met with the same issue.  I also tried 6320-6325 and still bupkis.

I have a no-ip host which is pointing to my modems external IP address. I have dynamic DNS setup in the router for my login information at noip. I have the noip's DUC running on the server.

When I go to [canyouseeme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) no ports are found open and the ones I have forwarded say that the connection was refused (as opposed to connection timed out).

I have been told that the fact that the router defaults to 10.0.0.x instead of 192.168.1.x is a reason it might not work right (and shows the router isn't setup right) but I don't know how to fix it. I was also told that settings in apache might need to be edited but I don't know how to do that. Others say that the modem might be refusing the connection but there's nothing in the settings of the modem to forward it farther.

The path to the internet for my main computer is internet->192.168.1.xx->10.0.0.1->10.0.0.4. Is the fact that it gets changed twice the problem? If so how do I fix this?

I followed everything that noip.com says I should which means it should be working but it's not. Can anyone help me as I'm about to resort to a hammer to "fix" it.

Comment: It is possible your ISP is blocking those ports. Try something way out of the normal range like 12345->80.

Comment: The answer to this is still going to be very long. Can you confirm that your dynamic DNS resolves to the same address that canyouseeme.org shows for you (this can be done using the ping tool even if you don't get a response from the computer it'll still show the IP)? BTW, for testing you may want to use the IP for the URL to access your server to remove this possible error. Also, does the modem also have a router built in (most do these days)? If it does, then you should either just use that router and remove the other one or set it up to be a 'bridge only' to make this easier.

Comment: Also, you probably have at least one firewall between all of those devices. Ensure that all firewalls are allowing HTTP traffic through (port 80); I'd also let ECHO\ICMP requests through on the modem to make this easier. The fact that you can use this on the Wifi tells you that you've probably got the server (and by extension Apache) itself setup correctly; it's just a matter of routing the outside traffic now

Comment: You should logon to this site before you make edits to your questions. If you don't, then your edits won't be applied until others approve them.